# AutoComplete Jquery Textbox --- > Identify Error

Tags: jquery

Am having a Autocomplete Text box using jquery.

If user types 3 characters am showing the list from DB. My problem is if user types his own thing and submit i need to warn him or fire some validation message ?

How do  i do this ?

If user type Own thing means --- For example

I have the following suggestion list in DB like

Apple
Orange
Grapes   and i don want user to type Gra  or app or something of tat sort which is not in DB

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "his own thing"?

Comment: updated as per the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select` and `change` event handlers when you call autocomplete.

For example:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: 'getlist.php', // for example
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // the user selected from drop-down
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        // the user input his own values..

        // $(this).val(''); // this code will reset the value to blank
    }
});
```